Initial curl_fetch_memory is slow, but faster in subsequent calls
I am trying to download some data from the url below using the curl-package. However, the first initial call is slow, but the subsequent calls are significantly faster. I have tested this on various R sessions, and if I make a call on a different R session, the unrelated R session is also faster. So I expect that I am doing something wrong.
Below is a MWE of how I am using the curl-package.
url <- "https://data-api.binance.vision/api/v3/klines?symbol=ETHUSDT&interval=1d&limit=1000&startTime=1702512000000&endTime=1719878400000"
handle <- curl::new_handle()

system.time(
  {
    curl::curl_fetch_memory(
      url    = url,
      handle = handle
    )
  }
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.039   0.004   2.088

system.time(
  {
    curl::curl_fetch_memory(
      url    = url,
      handle = handle
    )
  }
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.002   0.000   0.378

How can I setup the handle such that it will be as fast as the subsequent calls?
Created on 2024-07-03 with reprex v2.1.0
